# Using a binary search database within a search engine

Tags: javascript, c++, html, binary, search-engine

I own a music streaming search website.  I want to make a more robust search engine experience.  Adding a binary search into the search engine like Google has where if you start typing in a couple of keywords it would narrow down the search results from a database list to the ones container the same keywords.  For example if you typed in "lady" into the search engine, anything within the binary search's database that contains "lady" would appear.  I just do not know how to add it to my existing line of code for the search box.  Any ideas?

```
<div id="top_search">
    <form id="top_search_form">
        <input type="text" id="top_search_input" placeholder="Search Music" />
    </form>
</div>
```

Comment: Strictly speaking, Google is not a "binary search."  You might be looking for something like Lucene.

Comment: I dont think lucene is a good solution. If the streams catalog is updating constantly you have to re-index your luecen db each time. The best aproach IMHO is just a query.

Comment: Having to re-index is something that could be troublesome long term.  I think I will start using just a query to get my foot a little wet.  Im not that experienced in ajaxx live search.

Comment: Your code is html.  What does this have to do with C++ or Java or binary numbers?

Answer (score -2):

Recently i did somethin similar and i use this example as template,

http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_ajax_livesearch.asp

hope it helps.

Comment: Please read: [Are answers that just contain links elsewhere really “good answers”?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/8231/are-answers-that-just-contain-links-elsewhere-really-good-answers)

Comment: @RobertHarvey, sometimes -like this- links are a good answer.

Comment: The link molokoV gave was a good link in that it shows a foundation of what I was looking for.  Will I use it? Only for reference and as a foundation.  Robert lucene seems like a great tool for searches so I will be trying to get either to work on my site. Thank you both for input